# If $\varphi : A\to B$ is surjective, then is $GL_{0}\left(B\right)$ contained in $\varphi\left(GL\left(A\right)\right)$?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-algebras

Let $A$ and $B$ be two $C^*$-algebras. Suppose $\varphi : A\to B$ is a surjective $*$-homomorphism. Denote the set of invertible elements of $A$ by $GL\left(A\right)$ and denote the set of invertible elements ,whict are in the same connecting part with $1$, of $B$ by $GL_{0}\left(B\right)$. Then $GL_{0}\left(B\right)$ is contianed in $\varphi\left(GL\left(A\right)\right)$?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome on math.stackexchange :) Did you mean to phrase the last sentence as a question? Otherwise I cannot see one. If that is the case, please edit to correct.

Comment: Also, it would be lovely if people that vote to close on a person asking their very first question could be bothered to let them know how to improve. Playing nicely with other kids cannot be that hard... even some toddler manage to do it.

Comment: See I.1.a (page 7) here: https://home.iiserb.ac.in/~prahlad/documents/teaching/k_theory_notes.pdf. The crucial ingredient is that every element of $\mathrm{GL}_0(B)$ can be written as product of exponentials.